# How to create nodes in a loop and insert them to a linked list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Here is my structures:

```
typedef struct gene{
    char* name;
    int length;
    int* sequence;
} gene;

typedef struct genes{
    gene gene;
    struct genes* next;
} genes;
```

constructors:

```
genes* createGenes(gene newGene){
    genes* geneArr = malloc(sizeof(genes));
    if (NULL != geneArr){
        geneArr->gene = newGene;
        geneArr->next = NULL;
    }
    return geneArr;
}

void deleteGenes(genes* geneArr){
    if(NULL != geneArr->next){
        deleteGenes(geneArr->next);
    }
    free(geneArr);
}

genes* addGene(genes* geneList, gene newGene){
    genes* toAdd = createGenes(newGene);
    if (NULL != toAdd){
        geneList->next = toAdd;
    }
    return geneList;
}
```

and a function (it creates a sequence with the given length. For 5 -> `{2, 2, 2, 2, 2}`):

```
gene twosGene(char* name, int length){
    gene newGene;
    newGene.name = name;
    newGene.length = length;
    newGene.sequence = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * length);

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        newGene.sequence[i] = 2;
    }
    return newGene;
}
```

here is my `main()` function:

```
int main(){
    int count = 1;

    genes* geneArr = createGenes(twosGene("gene1", count++));

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        geneArr = addGene(geneArr, twosGene("geneLoop", count++));
    }

    genes* iter;
    for (iter = geneArr; NULL != iter; iter = iter->next) {
        printf("gene=%d\n", iter->gene.length);
        free(iter->gene.sequence);
    }

    deleteGenes(geneArr);

    return 0;
}
```

I expect this output:

```
gene=1
gene=2
gene=3
gene=4
gene=5
```

but instead I'm getting this:

```
gene=1
gene=5
```

Also when I use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), there is some leakage in my program.

```
==20580== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20580==     in use at exit: 132 bytes in 6 blocks
==20580==   total heap usage: 11 allocs, 5 frees, 1,244 bytes allocated
```

I cannot figure it out why. Thanks for your helps.

Comment: `twosGene` seems like a rather odd function--can you explain the significance of the magic number 2? What sort of structure are you expecting to create (the stdout doesn't print the sequence).

Comment: @ggorlen, I checked that, but he is returning (a copy of) the whole struct.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and not bits of source code that need to be stiched together so it can be compiled. You can [edit]  your question.

Comment: @ggorlen Actually I shortened my code to post a question and '2' is just some value, not mean anything.

Comment: Is `addGene` supposed to add to the end of the list or add to the beginning? At the moment it just overwrites the `next` pointer of the first element in the list, which isn't what you want.

Comment: @IanAbbott end of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within this function

```
genes* addGene(genes* geneList, gene newGene){
    genes* toAdd = createGenes(newGene);
    if (NULL != toAdd){
        geneList->next = toAdd;
    }
    return geneList;
}
```

you are always overwriting the data member next of the node initially created in the statement

```
genes* geneArr = createGenes(twosGene("gene1", count++));
```

It seems you want to add a new node to the end of the current list. In this case the function will look like

```
genes* addGene(genes* geneList, gene newGene){
    genes* toAdd = createGenes(newGene);
    if (NULL != toAdd){
        genes *current = geneList;

        while ( current->next != NULL ) current = current->next;
        current->next = toAdd;
    }
    return geneList;
}
```

However in general even this function definition is invalid because initially `geneList` can be equal to NULL. So using your approach the function should be rewritten the following way

```
genes* addGene(genes* geneList, gene newGene){
    genes* toAdd = createGenes(newGene);
    if (NULL != toAdd){
        if ( geneList == NULL )
        {
            geneList = toAdd;
        }
        else
        {
            genes *current = geneList;

            while ( current->next != NULL ) current = current->next;
            current->next = toAdd;
        }
    }

    return geneList;
}
```

However even this function implementation can be improved if to pass pointer to the head pointer of the list.

For example

```
int addGene( genes **geneList, gene newGene )
{
    genes* toAdd = createGenes(newGene);
    int success = toAdd != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        while ( *geneList != NULL ) geneList = &( *geneList )->next;
        *geneList = toAdd;
    }

    return success;
}
```

In this case the function can be called like

```
genes* geneArr = createGenes(twosGene("gene1", count++));

for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    addGene( &geneArr, twosGene("geneLoop", count++));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
genes* geneArr = createGenes(twosGene("gene1", count++));

for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    geneArr = addGene(geneArr, twosGene("geneLoop", count++));
}
```

the first allocates the head of the list. In the for-loop you next overwrite this head with every iteration. You should/could do:

```
genes* geneArr = createGenes(twosGene("gene1", count++));

genes *geneNext= geneArr;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    geneNext = addGene(geneNext, twosGene("geneLoop", count++));
}
```

Also, `addGene` must advance the pointer for the above to work.

```
genes* addGene(genes* geneList, gene newGene){
    genes* toAdd = createGenes(newGene);
    if (NULL != toAdd){
        geneList->next = toAdd;
        genelist= geneList->next;  // add this statement.
    }
    return geneList;
}
```

Now you can print it, as you still have the head.

Answer (score 1):

The `addGene` function is not adding to the end of the list. It is just linking the new gene to the first gene. Anything after the first gene in the list is "forgotten", leading to the memory leak, as reported by Valgrind.

Here is an updated version of the `addGenes` function that should work:

```
genes* addGene(genes* geneList, gene newGene){
    genes* toAdd = createGenes(newGene);
    if (NULL != toAdd){
        if (geneList == NULL){
            geneList = toAdd;
        } else {
            genes *last = geneList;
            while (last->next != NULL){
                last = last->next;
            }
            last->next = toAdd;
        }
    }
    return geneList;
}
```